# pythonic way of composing itemgetter and attrgetter?

Tags: python, closures, cython

I've got some code I'm porting to Cython which had a line like

```py
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.attr[item])
```

Is there a nice pythonic way of avoiding the closure with some combination of itemgetter and attrgetter?

Comment: Avoiding the closure meaning `lambda x=x`? Or something different?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, OP is using attribute get (`.attr`), item get (`[item]`) both which prevent use of `operator.attrgetter`, `operator.itemgetter`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to use the package `functional`:

```
from functional import compose
from operator import attrgetter, itemgetter
my_list.sort(key=compose(itemgetter(item), attrgetter('attr')))
```

Comment: functional is [available on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/functional/).

Answer (score -1):

The accepted self answer feels like a mistake/de-optimization to me.

My guess is that the unstated problem is that closures aren't supported inside `cpdef` functions. However closures are supported inside both `cdef` and `def` functions.

My view is that there's rarely a reason to use `cpdef` functions - they have all the disadvantages of `def` functions and all the disadvantages of `cdef` functions (plus a few more unique disadvantages, like no closures) so I usually treat them as the worst of all worlds. Ideally you'd just decide if something should be a Cython/C interface (`cdef`) or a Python interface `def` and use that. Also remember that the type of function makes little to no difference to how the code inside it is compiled, so a find/replace of `def` for `cpdef` really is redundant when porting to Cython.

Therefore for this case I would keep the closure as written in the original Python code and  pick one of:

1. Just keep it as a `def` function.
2. If you really need to call it from both Python and need the speed of a `cdef` call when calling it from Cython then write a `cdef` function and a really small `def` function wrapper for the `cdef` function.

The code in the accepted answer is de-optimizing an attribute lookup and an index into at least(?) 3 Python function calls, an attribute lookup, and an index.